# JSON output from web method

Tags: ajax, razor, fullcalendar

I have a web method returning JSON to a fullCalendar as event data but a "()" is added to it causing a parser error.

I am able to clip off the unwanted "()" and then attach the events with jQuery but obviously don't want to keep it this way.

The source of the data is a web method using Razor.  Using the JSON helper to encode the data results in a well formed JSON string, i.e. no "()".  Of course if I use encode I then would use Response.Write to send the data back to the AJAX function.  The same ill formed JSON data is recieved if I use JSON.Write(data, Response.Output).

Catching the returned data in the success function shows the data with the attached "()".

Here is a portion of the web method that returns the data:

```
    // convert the header names and data to strings 
    var rows = from e in cE
               select new
               {
                   id = e.EvId,
                   title = e.Title,
                   start = e.startT,
                   allDay = false,
                   end = e.endT,
                   backgroundColor = e.eventColor
               };

    string mJson = Json.Encode(rows);
    //Json.Write(rows, Response.Output);
    Response.Write(mJson.Trim());
```

here is the result of the encode:

```
    "[{\"id\":9,\"title\":\"new event\",\"start\":\"2012-05-29 19:00:00\",\"allDay\":false,\"end\":\"2012-05-29 20:00:00\",\"backgroundColor\":\"Orange    \"},{\"id\":9,\"title\":\"new event\",\"start\":\"2012-06-05 19:00:00\",\"allDay\":false,\"end\":\"2012-06-05 20:00:00\",\"backgroundColor\":\"Orange    \"},{\"id\":9,\"title\":\"new event\",\"start\":\"2012-06-12 19:00:00\",\"allDay\":false,\"end\":\"2012-06-12 20:00:00\",\"backgroundColor\":\"Orange    \"},{\"id\":10,\"title\":\"another\",\"start\":\"2012-06-22 19:00:00\",\"allDay\":false,\"end\":\"2012-06-22 19:45:00\",\"backgroundColor\":\"Orange    \"},{\"id\":10,\"title\":\"another\",\"start\":\"2012-06-29 19:00:00\",\"allDay\":false,\"end\":\"2012-06-29 19:45:00\",\"backgroundColor\":\"Orange    \"}]"  string
```

Here is what the AJAX success function shows as the recieved data:

```
    "[{"id":9,"title":"new event","start":"2012-05-29 19:00:00","allDay":false,"end":"2012-05-29 20:00:00","backgroundColor":"Orange    "},{"id":9,"title":"new event","start":"2012-06-05 19:00:00","allDay":false,"end":"2012-06-05 20:00:00","backgroundColor":"Orange    "},{"id":9,"title":"new event","start":"2012-06-12 19:00:00","allDay":false,"end":"2012-06-12 20:00:00","backgroundColor":"Orange    "},{"id":10,"title":"another","start":"2012-06-22 19:00:00","allDay":false,"end":"2012-06-22 19:45:00","backgroundColor":"Orange    "},{"id":10,"title":"another","start":"2012-06-29 19:00:00","allDay":false,"end":"2012-06-29 19:45:00","backgroundColor":"Orange    "}]();???"
```

Comment: What is the data *on the wire*? E.g. inspect with Firebug/Fiddler2/Developer Tools to make sure it wasn't introduced elsewhere for some silly reason. I think this is being added to "prevent direct execution of JSON", but the form looks a little bit different from those "busters"... either that or someone is trying to get the value to execute as a function...

Comment: Example of a ["buster"](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/samples/data_region/JSONParserSample.html)

Comment: Are you using jQuery for ajax? Plain XMLHttpRequest? It looks like something is expecting a function to come back from the ajax call (i.e. a JSONP call).

Comment: The final result is from Chrome Developer tools but is the same in firebug response header for the data request module. So the output from the Razor module is where the "()" is added.  It almost looks like something thinks it should be JSONP except that the JSON data should be inside the "()". Since mJson doesn't have this addition it is being added in the Response method.

Comment: where is question? I could now find any question mark but many comments.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: @user1442993 The end of the Returned JSON string is getting `()` appended to it. This looks like a fairly easy issue to work out. I cannot debug it right now as I am at work but when I get home I will load up my IDE there and look at it.